# Does it help to do any preprocessing before `FindSequenceFunction`?

Tags: symbolic, experimental-mathematics

I am always amazed how smart `FindSequenceFunction` can be in discovering general term formula for a sequence of rational numbers. The documentation says it can work not only with rational sequences (and if fact I saw this in several simple cases).

- Have you found it useful to do some preprocessing of a sequence when it consists not of rational numbers? For example, if every element has a form $p_n+q_n\sqrt2$, do you try to separate sequences $p_n$ and $q_n$.
- How do you handle sequences of symbolic polynomial `Root`s?
- Do you use any standard code for preprocessing?
- Maybe you noticed that some preprocessing helps with rational sequences as well?

Comment: Interesting to know this function! So I can get higher IQ test scores by cheating using Mathematica!

Comment: interesting, but without some example to work this seems practically out of scope of the site.